# php , convert to date from excel

Tags: php, excel

I am importing a excel , it seems from source the date is coming like this :
"2021-04-08T12:36:12+03:00"

i used the function

> public function transformDate($value)
> try {
> return  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value);
> } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
> return '-1';
> }

this function did a exception ,
if i used  strtotime(2021-04-08T12:36:12+03:00) , it return bad date like : 0616-05-07 00:05:00

i can't find the correct function

Comment: Have you checked what the exception message says?

Comment: I get a correct result with `strtotime`, post your full code: https://3v4l.org/GAnrt

Comment: My advice would be to use the `DateTime` class. Its constructor can parse this string [perfectly](https://3v4l.org/VfKa4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date string "2021-04-08T12:36:12+03:00" contains a time zone +03:00.
The best way is to use DateTime to keep the correct time zone.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("2021-04-08T12:36:12+03:00");
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
//2021-04-08 12:36:12 +0300
```

If the date is required for a different time zone, this can be done with setTimeZone().

```
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
//2021-04-08 11:36:12 Europe/Berlin
```

If we use strtotime and Date then we get a date and a time according to the setting of our server (My time zone is "Europe/Berlin").

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s e',strtotime("2021-04-08T12:36:12+03:00"));
//2021-04-08 11:36:12 Europe/Berlin
```